# Quickest/Best way to traverse XML with lxml in Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <root>
            <item>text</item>
            <item2>more text</item2>
            <targetroot>
                <targetcontainer>
                    <target>text i want to get</target>
                </targetcontainer>
                <targetcontainer>
                    <target>text i want to get</target>
                </targetcontainer>
            </targetroot>
            ...more items
        </root>
'''
```

With lxml I'm trying to acces the text in the element < target >. I've found a solution, but I'm sure there is a better, more efficient way to do this. My solution:

```
target = etree.XML(xml)

for x in target.getiterator('root'):
    item1 = x.findtext('item')
    for target in x.iterchildren('targetroot'):
        for t in target.iterchildren('targetcontainer'):
            targetText = t.findtext('target')
```

Although this works, as it gives me acces to all the elements in root as well as the target element, I'm having a hard time believing this is the most efficient solution.

So my question is this: is there a more efficient way to access the < target >'s texts while staying in the loop of root, because I also need access to the other elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp):

```
for x in target.xpath('/root/targetroot/targetcontainer/target'):
    print x.text
```

We ask all elements that match a *path*. In this case, the path is `/root/targetroot/targetcontainer/target`, which means

> all the `<target>` elements that are inside a `<targetcontainer>` element, inside a `<targetroot>` element, inside a `<root>` element. Also, the `<root>` element should be the document root because it is preceded by `/`, which means the beginning of the document.

Also, your XML document had two problems. First, the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` declaration should be the very first thing in the document - and in this example it is preceded by a newline and some space. Also, it is not a tag and should not be closed, so the `</xml>` at the end of your string should be removed. I already edited your question anyway.

**EDIT**: this solution can be improved yet. You do not need to pass all the path - you can just ask to all elements `<target>` inside the document. This is done by preceding the tag name by two slashes. Since you want *all* the `<target>` texts, independent of where they are, this can be a better solution. So, the loop above can be written just as:

```
for x in target.xpath('//target'):
    print x.text
```

I tried it at first but it did not worked. The problem, however, was the syntax problems in the XML, not the XPath, but I tried the other, longer path and forgot to retry this one. Sorry! Anyway, I hope I put some light about XPath nonetheless :)

Comment: The <xml> tags are my error, the actual xml has the right syntax. The xpath thing works great, thanks! Cleaner code = cleaner.

Comment: @Roland actually, it can be made still cleaner. I edited the answer, take a look!

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out when reading about xpath. Good edit though!